# Complex data frame transposition in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I've tried searching for an answer for this but most data.frame/matrix transpoitions aren't as complicated as I am trying to accomplish.  Basically I have a data.frame which looks like

```
          F    M    A
2008_b    1    5    6
2008_r    3    3    6
2008_a    4    1    5
2009_b    1    1    2
2009_r    5    4    9
2009_a    2    2    4
```

I'm trying to transpose it and rename the column and row names as such:

```
          F_b  M_b  A_b  F_r  M_r  A_r  F_a  M_a  A_a
2008        1    5    6    3    3    6    4    1    5
2009        1    1    2    5    4    9    2    2    4
```

Essentially every three rows are being collapsed in to a single row.  I assume this can be done with some clever plyr or reshape2 commands but I'm at a total loss how to accomplish it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

lvl <- c(outer(colnames(df), unique(gsub(".*_", "", rownames(df))), 
                       FUN=paste, sep="_"))


res <- cbind(Var1=row.names(df), df) %>%
                              gather(Var2, value, -Var1) %>% 
                              separate(Var1, c('Var11', 'Var12')) %>%
                              unite(VarN, Var2, Var12) %>%
                              mutate(VarN=factor(VarN, levels=lvl)) %>%
                              spread(VarN, value)

row.names(res) <- res[,1]
res1 <- res[,-1]
res1
#     F_b M_b A_b F_r M_r A_r F_a M_a A_a
#2008   1   5   6   3   3   6   4   1   5
#2009   1   1   2   5   4   9   2   2   4
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(F = c(1L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 5L, 2L), M = c(5L, 3L, 1L, 
1L, 4L, 2L), A = c(6L, 6L, 5L, 2L, 9L, 4L)), .Names = c("F", 
"M", "A"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("2008_b", "2008_r", 
"2008_a", "2009_b", "2009_r", "2009_a"))
```

Comment: Ok, that is close enough, unfortunately when I run this the separate() throws and error;

`Error: Values not split into 2 pieces at 1, 2, 3...etc.`

Comment: Nice answer (+1) - I wonder if you could use tidyr, e.g. `gather`, to replace the `melt(as.matrix(df))` so that you wouldn't need both packages? (Since my understanding is that tidyr replaced reshape2.)

Comment: @beginneR Thanks, I was thinking about using `gather` first but then I have to add the rownames as a separate column, which becomes a bit more ugly.

Comment: @beginneR I removed the `melt` part.